# "Is that why you know...?"

Tags: phrase-usage

Is there something wrong with that phrase? It has [0](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1280&bih=938&tbm=bks&q=%22Is%20that%20why%20you%20know%20%20%20%22&oq=%22Is%20that%20why%20you%20know%20%20%20%22&gs_l=serp.3...18814.19006.0.19183.3.3.0.0.0.0.174.174.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..3.0.0.VZEjdhwTDjs) results on Google Books.

Example sentence:

> "Is that why you know so much about those topics?"

Or maybe this alternative is more common?

> "That's why you know so much about those topics?"

Comment: Why Google Books especially? Your example sentence is slightly awkward, and the culprit is probably "those topics," but it is grammatically correct. " ... about this?" would be better, or " ... about these matters?" Also, try "how" instead of "why" and see what happens.

Comment: They can mean two different things. The first is perfectly ok if you're asking legitimately. The second *might* be taken as sarcastic.

Comment: @Ricky +1 — I'd be much more inclined to say 'Is that how you know…?'

Comment: "Is this" might be a bit more idiomatic than "Is that".  And, as anotherdave says, "how" might be more idiomatic than "why".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the sentences are grammatically correct, the difference is, what you are emphasising at.
In the first sentence "those topics" is being emphasised.